# Reading .txt file with Tab and Backspace as separators

Tags: r, import, read.table

I am trying import data from a .txt file 
The columns are separated with \  and the rows are separated by tabs.

The file looks like that:

`"COL1"\"COL2"\"COL3"\"COL4"  "Value"\1\"Value2"\"103"    "Value"\1\"Value2"\"103"    "Value"\1\"Value2"\"103"    "Value"\1\"Value2"\"103"    "Value"\1\"Value2"\"103"    "Value"\1\"Value2"\"103"    "Value"\1\"Value2"\"103"`

The size of the file is ~100MB
Does anyone know a good and fast way to import the data?

i have tried
read./_delim
read./_table
read.tsv

Comment: Please show your actual R commands that you tried including all arguments and the errors you got (if any)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the separator. The "\" character is a metacharacter (it's very special). Unless you escape it, it is used to escape other metacharacters. SO, you have to escape it!

```
dat <- read.csv("file.txt", sep="\\")
```

or if that takes too long:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("file.txt", sep="\\")
    COL1 COL2   COL3 COL4
1: Value    1 Value2  103
2: Value    1 Value2  103
3: Value    1 Value2  103
4: Value    1 Value2  103
5: Value    1 Value2  103
6: Value    1 Value2  103
7: Value    1 Value2  103
```

Comment: Thank you Edward!  
Although this still leads to all rows being read in as one row since the row separator is TAB. Do you know a way to solve that?